# Random record selection - VMS / RDB

Tags: sql, vms, oracle-rdb

I have been asked for a SQL statement to retrieve an arbitrary number of rows, randomly selected, from a data table in a database hosted on Oracle RDB on VMS.

In MS SQL, it would simply be:

```
SELECT TOP 5 * 
FROM MyTable  
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

But I cannot find an equivalent method for RDB/VMS.

"Proper" Oracle would be:

```
ORDER BY dbms_random.VALUE
```

However, that does not appear to be supoprted in RDB on VMS.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable 
ORDER BY NEWID()
LIMIT to 5
```

Comment: I doubt that you could have a column named NEWID() with RDB.

Comment: NEWID() is an MS SQL function to generate a new GUID. If a new GUID is created with every row's evaluation, their sort order would be pseudo-random. It's not a great method due to the CPU load, but it works well. However, it's not available in RDB on VMS.  I put it in the post to demonstrate what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the "RDB way" to do it, but if the records have sequential IDs, find out the hightest-number ID and then by scripting generate a random list of IDs to fetch. Something like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Then in Python: `records = random.sample(range(topId), 5)`